# CA1806 DoNotIgnoreMethodResults raised erroneously?

Tags: c#, code-analysis

Hence my following code:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
internal static void WriteGLResult(string methodName, object result,
    params object[] args)
{
    string message = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}({1}) = {2}",
        methodName, String.Join(", ", args), result);
    Write(LogType.Information, Category.GLResult, 2, message);
}
```

I'm clearly assigning the `String.Format()` result to the variable `message`. I'm also passing that instance to the Write method afterwards. Yet CA1806 is raised:

> **Do not ignore method results**
>
> 'Log.WriteGLResult(string, object, params object[])' calls 'string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params object[])' but does not use the new string instance that the method returns. Pass the instance as an argument to another method, assign the instance to a variable, or remove the call if it is unnecessary.`

In the called `Write` method, I'm also using the string, there named `format`, as it's used like this:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private static void Write(LogType logType, Category category, int stackTraceFrameSkips,
    string format, params object[] args)
{
    // ...
    string message = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args);
    // ...
}
```

I don't know how to fix this warning. And I doubt CA raises this erroneously.

Can you help me?

Comment: How is `Write` defined? I ask because my first guess is that it's got the [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) applied to it and the call ends up removed before CA determines whether `message` is ever used. Could you try to provide a minimal complete program that has the problem you describe?

Comment: @hvd: Yes, that is it. All the write calls (this and the called one) are decorated with a `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute. If I build without these, I get no warning. I added it to the snippets in my question. Add it as an answer and I'll accept. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from the comments:

Since `Write` is defined as

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private static void Write(LogType logType, Category category, int stackTraceFrameSkips,
    string format, params object[] args)
```

that means the calls to `Write` will be completely removed when the `DEBUG` symbol is not defined. The code analysis runs later, and by that time it can determine (correctly) that `message` is never used.

For something that neither warns in debug nor in release mode, you *might* want to move the call to `String.Format` directly into the method arguments:

```
Write(LogType.Information, Category.GLResult, 2,
    String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}({1}) = {2}",
    methodName, String.Join(", ", args), result));
```

This should make sure that `String.Format` is only called when `Write` will be called.